# Using data from webpages to make a calculation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I would like to extract specific data from a webpage then open a specific webpage based on what that data is. In the form of an if statement.

Say for example I google the olympics (https://www.google.com/#safe=off&hl=en&q=olympics&btnK=Google+Search)

It says it is in "Rio" right now. Say based on "Rio" I have a link that directs to Wikipedia and if it said something other than "Rio" it directs to www.google.com. I need to find a way to be able to pinpoint the data I need from another webpage then make a decision based off of that. The hard part being assigning that data to a variable.

I would like to do this in jQuery if at all possible. If not what language what I need to do this? Is there a specific name for this type of thing (pulling data off of webpages) and are there any resources so I can learn more about it?

Thank you

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You want to parse the rendered in browser HTML page using javascript, then find some data (e.g. `var data = $('#some-element').val()), and then, according to this data - relocate the user to another webpage? If so, I don't really understand what exact problem are you facing with that

Comment: You should first consider how you are going to parse the response you're receiving. You say `It says it is in "Rio" right now`, but how are you proposing you get at that data? Start incrementally and work toward a solution.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. That is precisely what I am asking. How do I get to that piece of data so I can use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its what you are looking for. Correct me if i'm wrong
You can use the PHP method on a file called go.php

```
<?echo get_file_contents($_GET['a']); ?>
```

and call it from AJAX using:

```
$.get("go.php?a=https://google.com", function(data){
  //Your code....
});
```

IMPORTANT: DON'T FORGET THE HTTP OR HTTPS, if you forget it, go.php will try to find google.com in your server. 
This method doesn't load the images because it tries to load them from your server

Comment: Won't this store the entire page rather than something specific. If so... Is there a way to easy break that data up into variables? Or search through it somehow? Is it like a text file with everything from source? if so that might be workable.

Comment: This seems like the simplest way to do it. Just grabbing all of the data then using file i/o techniques to get the data desired... Can be lengthy and slow. Appreciate the help. I am looking for a faster method, but this does work.